# Loading Config and Setting a Config Value in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I try to create application with back-end and frond-end. The folder structure as follows(only show config file position to explain problem)

```
+root
|-admin
|-application
  |—backend
    |—config
      |—config.php
  |—frontend
    |—config 
      |—config.php
|-system
```

Using back-end admin panel I try to change config value in both back-end and frond-end config.php value. But I fail to change it in front-end config.php file. I don’t need database based solution for this.

Comment: I just use $this->load->config('../../frontend/config/config', TRUE) to load frontend/config/config.php and using $this->config->item('item name'); try to fetched value in that config file. But it gave me only backend/config/config.php value.. Please give me some suggestion to solve this. Thanks Yan!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) I got this:

`Note: CodeIgniter always tries to load the configuration files for the current environment first. If the file does not exist, the global config file (i.e., the one in application/config/) is loaded. This means you are not obligated to place all of your configuration files in an environment folder − only the files that change per environment.`

So based on that information, I think the problem is when you are calling it, maybe a problem with your path.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, <br/> I try to load front-end config/config.php file as follows. <br/>$this->load->config('../../frontend/config/config', TRUE);<br/> And the after i try to fetching Config Items using <br/> $this->config->item('item name'); <br/> But it only fetched backend/config/config.php value only.. So please give me a simple example to solve this.